# C++ GUI testing of wizard installation

Tags: c++, user-interface, testing, installation

I'm a student (studying in programming) doing an intership in a company, but was hired in the department of "testing".

I am asked to create a c++ program to automate (for testing purposes) the installation of the software developed in house.

The installation goes through a Wizard to choose a couple of options (checkbox, dropdownlist, button, radiobutton) and then proceeds to install everything (it also asks at the end if the user wants to install another component).

The main idea is to set all the options of the installation in a window of the program, which would install the software afterward. The tester won't have to stay and set the "install options" manually during the completion of the installation.

What I want to know is, is it possible to make it as a C++ app? And, if yes, and do you know any library that would be useful for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys).

Comment: thank you, i'll use just that. I was happy to try to code in C++, but at the end of the internship I'm  pretty sure I wouldn't be able to finish what the guy wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Qt framework which has a QWizard class for writing wizards in C++.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwizard.html

If you haven't used Qt before, picking up Qt basics (which should be enough to let you achieve your wizard) would be very easy and less time taking for you if your OOP is clear.